# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't recognize my Bq Ubuntu Edition smartphone

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, phone

When I connect my BQ Ubuntu via USB  to Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 nothing happens but I checked it with a Windows Xp computer and it runs ok.

Please some help!

*Ubuntu just released an update and now it works for me.

Comment: no problems here (lubuntu 14.04). I open the file manager and in **places** see the phone **Aquaris E4.5**, actually the path is **mtp://[usb:001,003]/Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition**.

Comment: No in my computer. Any device is shown in Places.

Comment: you are right. now I am at work and I have **ubuntu 13.10** but it does not recognize the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried and had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. 
Then I unplugged it and unlocked the phone (I have a PIN lock). I tried again after having unlocked the phone and it worked.

Comment: That doesn't run for me either even running in a 14.04 live.

Comment: This worked for me on an Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, but it seems that I found a solution for me. I was plugging it to a USB hub and it didn't recognize it. Now I tried to plug it directly to one of my computers USB ports and that worked just fine. I hope that helps!

Comment: So I don't have a hub, I plug it directly to my computer USB ports but nothing happens. I tried it with a Ubuntu 14.04 live pendrive getting the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the instructions of **write-mem** in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702. Previously, I have also installed **mtpfs**, but do not know if it was necessary.

Comment: But that is for Android devices, I can connect my Samsung Android without problems to Ubuntu 14.04. As well as I am not an advanced user to do that.

Comment: I need to do that for my **bq ubuntu edition** in my ubuntu desktop. The strange thing is that my lubuntu laptop recognizes the phone directly.

Comment: NO - *If you get it, mark the header of the question as SOLVED, please.'* - on this site, use the tick mark next to the answer that helped to close the question, and accept that answer - if you find your own solution, you can add your own answer and accept that.